# count if there are dates in array that match condition

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I'm a noob that is playing with calculators for fun. As a learning experience, I decided to make a maternity leave pay calculator for my country but I'm stuck at the working days calculations. For some reason, the code counts all the days in the holiday array and not the ones in the specified range between the startDate and the endDate. I've been stuck for days. I've added *new Date* in front of *element* in the conditions thinking it was a formatting issue but the result is the same.

here is the code.

Edit: The part with the issue is marked  /* Here is the code with the calc issue */ it's supposed to count the matches in the holiday array of dates that are within the given start and end dates while excluding/ignoring them if they fall on a weekend.

```js
function calculate() {
      var day = document.first.len11c.value;
      var mon = document.first.len12c.value;
      var year = document.first.len13c.value;
      var ylen = year.length;
      var m = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov",
        "Dec");
      var curd = new Date(year, mon - 1, day);
      var res2 = curd.getMonth();
      var res = new Date();
      var diff = Date.UTC(res.getFullYear(), res.getMonth() - 1, res.getDay(), 0, 0, 0) - Date.UTC(curd.getFullYear(), curd.getMonth() - 1, curd.getDay(), 0, 0, 0);
      var secleft = diff / 1000 / 60;
      var hrsleft = secleft / 60;
      var daysleft = hrsleft / 24;
      //if(res2 == (mon-1) && daysleft < 300 && year!="")
      if (year != "" && ylen > 3) {
        var fte = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) - 45);
        document.first.fte.value = fte.getDate() + " " + m[fte.getMonth()] + " " + fte.getFullYear();
        var ste = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) + 89);
        document.first.ste.value = ste.getDate() + " " + m[ste.getMonth()] + " " + ste.getFullYear();
        var dd = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) + 364);
        document.first.dd.value = dd.getDate() + " " + m[dd.getMonth()] + " " + dd.getFullYear();
        var dd2 = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) + 730);
        document.first.dd2.value = dd2.getDate() + " " + m[dd2.getMonth()] + " " + dd2.getFullYear();
        var YM1 = new Date(year, parseInt(mon - 1) - 1);
        document.first.YM1.value = YM1.getFullYear();
        var TM1 = new Date(year, parseInt(mon - 1) - 1, day = 1);
        document.first.TM1.value = m[TM1.getMonth()];


        // calculates workdays 
        /* Two working days and an sunday (not working day) */
        var startDate = new Date(year, (mon - 1) - 1, day = 1);
        var endDate = new Date(year, (mon - 1), 0);
  
        // Validate input
        if (endDate <= startDate) {
          return 0;
        }
        // Calculate days between dates
        var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
        startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1); // Start just after midnight
        endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // End just before midnight
        var diff = endDate - startDate; // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
        var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);
        // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
        var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
        days -= weeks * 2;
        // Handle special cases
        var startDay = startDate.getDay();
        var endDay = endDate.getDay();
        // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
        if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) {
          days--
        }
        //// Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
        if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) {
          days--
        }

        /* Here is the code with the calc issue */
        var daysH = 0;
        var holiday = ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-03', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-20', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-25', '2020-09-07', '2020-09-22', '2020-12-24', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-28', '2021-01-01', '2021-03-03', '2021-04-30', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-06', '2021-05-24', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-22', '2021-12-24', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-26', '2021-12-27', '2021-12-28', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-03', '2022-04-22', '2022-04-25', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-06', '2022-05-24', '2022-09-06', '2022-09-22', '2022-12-24', '2022-12-25', '2022-12-26', '2022-12-27', '2022-12-28', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-03-03', '2023-04-14', '2023-04-17', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-08', '2023-05-24', '2023-09-06', '2023-09-22', '2023-12-25', '2023-12-26', '2023-12-27', '2024-01-01', '2024-03-04', '2024-05-01', '2024-05-03', '2024-05-06', '2024-05-06', '2024-05-24', '2024-09-06', '2024-09-23', '2024-12-24', '2024-12-25', '2024-12-26', '2025-01-01', '2025-04-20', '2025-05-01', '2025-05-06', '2025-05-24', '2025-09-06', '2025-09-22', '2025-12-24', '2025-12-25', '2025-12-26', '2026-01-01', '2026-03-03', '2026-04-12', '2026-05-01', '2026-05-06', '2026-05-24', '2026-09-06', '2026-09-22', '2026-12-24', '2026-12-25', '2026-12-26', '2027-01-01', '2027-03-03', '2027-04-30', '2027-05-01', '2027-05-02', '2027-05-06', '2027-05-24', '2027-09-06', '2027-09-22', '2027-12-24', '2027-12-25', '2027-12-26', '2028-01-01', '2028-03-03', '2028-04-14', '2028-05-01', '2028-05-06', '2028-05-24', '2028-09-06', '2028-09-22', '2028-12-24', '2028-12-25', '2028-12-26', '2029-01-01', '2029-03-03', '2029-04-06', '2029-04-07', '2029-04-08', '2029-05-01', '2029-05-06', '2029-05-24', '2029-09-06', '2029-09-22', '2029-12-24', '2029-12-25', '2029-12-26', '2030-01-01', '2030-03-03', '2030-04-26', '2030-04-27', '2030-04-28', '2030-05-01', '2030-05-06', '2030-05-24', '2030-09-06', '2030-09-22', '2030-12-24', '2030-12-25', '2030-12-26', '2022-03-03', '2019-01-01', '2019-03-03', '2019-04-28', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-24', '2019-09-06', '2019-09-22', '2019-12-24', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26'];
        holiday.forEach(day => {
          if ((new Date(day) >= startDate) && (new Date(day) <= endDate)); {
            if ((new Date(day).getDay() % 6) != 0);
            daysH++;
          }
        });
        var WD = (days - daysH);
        document.first.WD.value = WD;
      } else {
        alert("Date is not valid");
      }
    }

    function isNumber(evt) {
      evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

```css
    .lefttt {
      float: left;
      color: #3D366F;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    
    .tboxx {
      width: 45% !important;
    }
    
    .frmss {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 0.3em;
      color: #333;
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .frmss input[type="text"],
    [type="password"],
    [type="file"],
    textarea,
    select {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 0.35em;
      height: 35px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      padding: 0 0.5%;
      width: 99%;
    }
    
    .frmss input[type="submit"],
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="button"],
    button,
    .yellow_button,
    .blue_button {
      border: medium none;
      border-radius: 0.3em;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 10px 0;
      padding: 7px 14px;
    }
    
    .frmss input[type="reset"] {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ee765d;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #d95e44;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #8c3736;
    }
    
    input[type="button"],
    button,
    .blue_button {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #468cd2;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #3277bc;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #214d73;
    }
    
    .new {
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .frmss {
        width: 90% !important;
      }
      .tboxx {
        width: 95% !Important;
      }
      .frmss input[type="text"],
      [type="password"],
      [type="file"],
      textarea,
      select {
        width: 95% !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src=" https://MomentJS.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <div class='resp_code2'>
    <p align='center'>
      <h2 align='center'>Dates Calculator
      </h2>
    </p>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <form id='tab' name=first class='frmss'>
      <div>
        <div align='center'><label>Enter due date:</label></div><br>
        <div class="group_con2">
          <label class='lefttt'>day: </label>
          <select name=len11c>
            <option name=1 value=1>1</option>
            <option name=2 value=2>2</option>
            <option name=3 value=3>3</option>
            <option name=4 value=4>4</option>
            <option name=5 value=5>5</option>
            <option name=6 value=6>6</option>
            <option name=7 value=7>7</option>
            <option name=8 value=8>8</option>
            <option name=9 value=9>9</option>
            <option name=10 value=10>10</option>
            <option name=11 value=11>11</option>
            <option name=12 value=12>12</option>
            <option name=13 value=13>13</option>
            <option name=14 value=14>14</option>
            <option name=15 value=15>15</option>
            <option name=16 value=16>16</option>
            <option name=17 value=17>17</option>
            <option name=18 value=18>18</option>
            <option name=19 value=19>19</option>
            <option name=20 value=20>20</option>
            <option name=21 value=21>21</option>
            <option name=22 value=22>22</option>
            <option name=23 value=23>23</option>
            <option name=24 value=24>24</option>
            <option name=25 value=25>25</option>
            <option name=26 value=26>26</option>
            <option name=27 value=27>27</option>
            <option name=28 value=28>28</option>
            <option name=29 value=29>29</option>
            <option name=30 value=30>30</option>
            <option name=31 value=31>31</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="group_con2"><label class='lefttt'>Month:</label>
          <select name=len12c>
            <option name=1 value=1>Jan</option>
            <option name=2 value=2>Feb</option>
            <option name=3 value=3>March</option>
            <option name=4 value=4>April</option>
            <option name=5 value=5>May</option>
            <option name=6 value=6>June</option>
            <option name=7 value=7>July</option>
            <option name=8 value=8>Aug</option>
            <option name=9 value=9>Sept</option>
            <option name=10 value=10>Oct</option>
            <option name=11 value=11>NOV</option>
            <option name=12 value=12>Dec</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class='group_con2'><label class='lefttt'>Year:</label>
          <input name=len13c type=text onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength='4'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div align='center'>
        <input type=button name=cc2 value=Calculate onClick="calculate()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
      </div>
      <div align='center'>
        <h5></h5>
      </div>

      <div> <label class='lefttt'>1st day of sick leave :</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=fte> </div>
      <div> <label class='lefttt'>last day of sick leave:</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=ste> </div>
      <div> <label class='lefttt'> 1st year maternity end date :</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=dd> </div>
      <div> <label class='lefttt'>2nd year maternity end date  :</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=dd2> </div>
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>



      <title>PASTCALCDAY</title>

      <style>
        teble {
          width: 400px;
        }
        
        th,
        caption {
          text-align: left;
        }
        
        table,
        th,
        td {
          border: 1px solid #333;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        th,
        td {
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #FBEAFF;
        }
        
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: #B39CD0;
        }
      </style>


      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>

      <table>
        <caption> Calculating daily compensation</caption>
        <caption> (Needed data 24 moths before 1st day of sick leave </caption>

        <tr>
          <th>year</th>
          <th>month</th>
          <th>Working days (without Holidays)</th>
        </tr>
        <td> <input type=text readonly name=YM1> </td>
        <td> <input type=text readonly name=TM1> </td>
        <td> <input type=text readonly name=WD> </td>


      </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to look through. Can you pare it down to just show the code that is misbehaving, and describe what you expect it to do?

Comment: I would recommend to start with splitting that up into separate files (html, js, css). After that focus on making the code more readable; better variable names and such.

Comment: i made your code a working snippet. The point is that you are embedding two different jquery versions one after the other but there should be just one. Fix the scripts and the order they are loaded and then update your question accordingly

Comment: @SimonBrahan I marked the code with /* Here is the code with the calc issue */ . (The character restriction doesn't allow me to add it here because it's too long) It's supposed to count the matches in the holiday array of dates that are within the given start and end dates while excluding/ignoring them if they fall on a weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Check this line

```
if ((new Date(day) >= startDate) && (new Date(day) <= endDate)); {
```

Remove the `;`

```js
function calculate() {
      var day = document.first.len11c.value;
      var mon = document.first.len12c.value;
      var year = document.first.len13c.value;
      var ylen = year.length;
      var m = new Array("Jan", "Feb", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug", "Sept", "Oct", "Nov",
        "Dec");
      var curd = new Date(year, mon - 1, day);
      var res2 = curd.getMonth();
      var res = new Date();
      var diff = Date.UTC(res.getFullYear(), res.getMonth() - 1, res.getDay(), 0, 0, 0) - Date.UTC(curd.getFullYear(), curd.getMonth() - 1, curd.getDay(), 0, 0, 0);
      var secleft = diff / 1000 / 60;
      var hrsleft = secleft / 60;
      var daysleft = hrsleft / 24;
      //if(res2 == (mon-1) && daysleft < 300 && year!="")
      if (year != "" && ylen > 3) {
        var fte = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) - 45);
        document.first.fte.value = fte.getDate() + " " + m[fte.getMonth()] + " " + fte.getFullYear();
        var ste = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) + 89);
        document.first.ste.value = ste.getDate() + " " + m[ste.getMonth()] + " " + ste.getFullYear();
        var dd = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) + 364);
        document.first.dd.value = dd.getDate() + " " + m[dd.getMonth()] + " " + dd.getFullYear();
        var dd2 = new Date(year, mon - 1, parseInt(day) + 730);
        document.first.dd2.value = dd2.getDate() + " " + m[dd2.getMonth()] + " " + dd2.getFullYear();
        var YM1 = new Date(year, parseInt(mon - 1) - 1);
        document.first.YM1.value = YM1.getFullYear();
        var TM1 = new Date(year, parseInt(mon - 1) - 1, day = 1);
        document.first.TM1.value = m[TM1.getMonth()];


        // calculates workdays 
        /* Two working days and an sunday (not working day) */
        var startDate = new Date(year, (mon - 1) - 1, day = 1);
        //startDate.setSeconds(Date.parse(startDate));
        //\document.first.startDate = startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+[startDate.getMonth()+1]+"-"+startDate.getDate();
        //document.first.startDate.value=startDate;
        var endDate = new Date(year, (mon - 1), 0);
        //document.first.endDate.value=endDate;
        //endDate.setSeconds(Date.parse(endDate));
        // document.first.endDate = endDate.getFullYear()+"-"+[endDate.getMonth()+1]+"-"+endDate.getDate();
        // Validate input
        if (endDate <= startDate) {
          return 0;
        }
        // Calculate days between dates
        var millisecondsPerDay = 86400 * 1000; // Day in milliseconds
        startDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 1); // Start just after midnight
        endDate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999); // End just before midnight
        var diff = endDate - startDate; // Milliseconds between datetime objects    
        var days = Math.ceil(diff / millisecondsPerDay);
        // Subtract two weekend days for every week in between
        var weeks = Math.floor(days / 7);
        days -= weeks * 2;
        // document.first.weeks.value =weeks;
        // Handle special cases
        var startDay = startDate.getDay();
        //document.first.startDay.value=startDay;
        var endDay = endDate.getDay();
        // document.first.endDay.value=endDay;
        // ==Remove weekend not previously removed.   
        //if (startDay - endDay > 1) { (days -= 2); } //no need for it 
        // Remove start day if span starts on Sunday but ends before Saturday
        if (startDay == 0 && endDay != 6) {
          days--
        }
        //// Remove end day if span ends on Saturday but starts after Sunday
        if (endDay == 6 && startDay != 0) {
          days--
        }
        // document.first.days.value=days; //check for no weekends; 


        /* Here is the code with the calc issue */
        var daysH = 0;
        var holiday = ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-03', '2020-04-17', '2020-04-20', '2020-05-01', '2020-05-06', '2020-05-25', '2020-09-07', '2020-09-22', '2020-12-24', '2020-12-25', '2020-12-28', '2021-01-01', '2021-03-03', '2021-04-30', '2021-05-01', '2021-05-02', '2021-05-03', '2021-05-04', '2021-05-06', '2021-05-24', '2021-09-06', '2021-09-22', '2021-12-24', '2021-12-25', '2021-12-26', '2021-12-27', '2021-12-28', '2022-01-01', '2022-01-03', '2022-04-22', '2022-04-25', '2022-05-02', '2022-05-06', '2022-05-24', '2022-09-06', '2022-09-22', '2022-12-24', '2022-12-25', '2022-12-26', '2022-12-27', '2022-12-28', '2023-01-01', '2023-01-02', '2023-03-03', '2023-04-14', '2023-04-17', '2023-05-01', '2023-05-08', '2023-05-24', '2023-09-06', '2023-09-22', '2023-12-25', '2023-12-26', '2023-12-27', '2024-01-01', '2024-03-04', '2024-05-01', '2024-05-03', '2024-05-06', '2024-05-06', '2024-05-24', '2024-09-06', '2024-09-23', '2024-12-24', '2024-12-25', '2024-12-26', '2025-01-01', '2025-04-20', '2025-05-01', '2025-05-06', '2025-05-24', '2025-09-06', '2025-09-22', '2025-12-24', '2025-12-25', '2025-12-26', '2026-01-01', '2026-03-03', '2026-04-12', '2026-05-01', '2026-05-06', '2026-05-24', '2026-09-06', '2026-09-22', '2026-12-24', '2026-12-25', '2026-12-26', '2027-01-01', '2027-03-03', '2027-04-30', '2027-05-01', '2027-05-02', '2027-05-06', '2027-05-24', '2027-09-06', '2027-09-22', '2027-12-24', '2027-12-25', '2027-12-26', '2028-01-01', '2028-03-03', '2028-04-14', '2028-05-01', '2028-05-06', '2028-05-24', '2028-09-06', '2028-09-22', '2028-12-24', '2028-12-25', '2028-12-26', '2029-01-01', '2029-03-03', '2029-04-06', '2029-04-07', '2029-04-08', '2029-05-01', '2029-05-06', '2029-05-24', '2029-09-06', '2029-09-22', '2029-12-24', '2029-12-25', '2029-12-26', '2030-01-01', '2030-03-03', '2030-04-26', '2030-04-27', '2030-04-28', '2030-05-01', '2030-05-06', '2030-05-24', '2030-09-06', '2030-09-22', '2030-12-24', '2030-12-25', '2030-12-26', '2022-03-03', '2019-01-01', '2019-03-03', '2019-04-28', '2019-05-01', '2019-05-06', '2019-05-24', '2019-09-06', '2019-09-22', '2019-12-24', '2019-12-25', '2019-12-26'];
        holiday.forEach(day => {
          if ((new Date(day) >= startDate) && (new Date(day) <= endDate)) {
            if ((new Date(day).getDay() % 6) != 0)
               daysH++;
          }
        });
        var WD = (days - daysH);
        document.first.WD.value = WD;
      } else {
        alert("Date is not valid");
      }
    }

    function isNumber(evt) {
      evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
      var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
```

```css
.lefttt {
      float: left;
      color: #3D366F;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    
    .tboxx {
      width: 45% !important;
    }
    
    .frmss {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 0.3em;
      color: #333;
      font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
      font-size: 0.9em;
      line-height: 1.2em;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 10px;
      width: 50%;
    }
    
    .frmss input[type="text"],
    [type="password"],
    [type="file"],
    textarea,
    select {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      border-radius: 0.35em;
      height: 35px;
      margin-bottom: 15px;
      margin-top: 5px;
      padding: 0 0.5%;
      width: 99%;
    }
    
    .frmss input[type="submit"],
    input[type="reset"],
    input[type="button"],
    button,
    .yellow_button,
    .blue_button {
      border: medium none;
      border-radius: 0.3em;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin: 10px 0;
      padding: 7px 14px;
    }
    
    .frmss input[type="reset"] {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ee765d;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #d95e44;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #8c3736;
    }
    
    input[type="button"],
    button,
    .blue_button {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #468cd2;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #3277bc;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #214d73;
    }
    
    .new {
      padding: 16px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
      .frmss {
        width: 90% !important;
      }
      .tboxx {
        width: 95% !Important;
      }
      .frmss input[type="text"],
      [type="password"],
      [type="file"],
      textarea,
      select {
        width: 95% !important;
      }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/JavaScript" src=" https://MomentJS.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <div class='resp_code2'>
    <p align='center'>
      <h2 align='center'>Dates Calculator
      </h2>
    </p>
    <div class='clear'></div>
    <form id='tab' name=first class='frmss'>
      <div>
        <div align='center'><label>Enter due date:</label></div><br>
        <div class="group_con2">
          <label class='lefttt'>day: </label>
          <select name=len11c>
            <option name=1 value=1>1</option>
            <option name=2 value=2>2</option>
            <option name=3 value=3>3</option>
            <option name=4 value=4>4</option>
            <option name=5 value=5>5</option>
            <option name=6 value=6>6</option>
            <option name=7 value=7>7</option>
            <option name=8 value=8>8</option>
            <option name=9 value=9>9</option>
            <option name=10 value=10>10</option>
            <option name=11 value=11>11</option>
            <option name=12 value=12>12</option>
            <option name=13 value=13>13</option>
            <option name=14 value=14>14</option>
            <option name=15 value=15>15</option>
            <option name=16 value=16>16</option>
            <option name=17 value=17>17</option>
            <option name=18 value=18>18</option>
            <option name=19 value=19>19</option>
            <option name=20 value=20>20</option>
            <option name=21 value=21>21</option>
            <option name=22 value=22>22</option>
            <option name=23 value=23>23</option>
            <option name=24 value=24>24</option>
            <option name=25 value=25>25</option>
            <option name=26 value=26>26</option>
            <option name=27 value=27>27</option>
            <option name=28 value=28>28</option>
            <option name=29 value=29>29</option>
            <option name=30 value=30>30</option>
            <option name=31 value=31>31</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="group_con2"><label class='lefttt'>Month:</label>
          <select name=len12c>
            <option name=1 value=1>Jan</option>
            <option name=2 value=2>Feb</option>
            <option name=3 value=3>March</option>
            <option name=4 value=4>April</option>
            <option name=5 value=5>May</option>
            <option name=6 value=6>June</option>
            <option name=7 value=7>July</option>
            <option name=8 value=8>Aug</option>
            <option name=9 value=9>Sept</option>
            <option name=10 value=10>Oct</option>
            <option name=11 value=11>NOV</option>
            <option name=12 value=12>Dec</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class='group_con2'><label class='lefttt'>Year:</label>
          <input name=len13c type=text onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" maxlength='4'>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div align='center'>
        <input type=button name=cc2 value=Calculate onClick="calculate()">
        <input type="reset" value="Clear">
      </div>
      <div align='center'>
        <h5></h5>
      </div>

      <div> <label class='lefttt'>1st day of sick leave :</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=fte> </div>
      <div> <label class='lefttt'>last day of sick leave:</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=ste> </div>
      <div> <label class='lefttt'> 1st year maternity end date :</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=dd> </div>
      <div> <label class='lefttt'>2nd year maternity end date  :</label>
        <input type=text readonly name=dd2> </div>
      <script type="text/javascript"></script>



      <title>PASTCALCDAY</title>

      <style>
        teble {
          width: 400px;
        }
        
        th,
        caption {
          text-align: left;
        }
        
        table,
        th,
        td {
          border: 1px solid #333;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        
        th,
        td {
          padding: 10px;
        }
        
        tr:nth-child(even) {
          background-color: #FBEAFF;
        }
        
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
          background-color: #B39CD0;
        }
      </style>


      <script type="text/javascript">
      </script>

      <table>
        <caption> Calculating daily compensation</caption>
        <caption> (Needed data 24 moths before 1st day of sick leave </caption>

        <tr>
          <th>year</th>
          <th>month</th>
          <th>Working days (without Holidays)</th>
        </tr>
        <td> <input type=text readonly name=YM1> </td>
        <td> <input type=text readonly name=TM1> </td>
        <td> <input type=text readonly name=WD> </td>


      </table>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

What happens is that the `;` closes the current instruction (the if). The brackets become superfluous but do not create an error. This means the code after the condition executes no matter what.

Comment: Ok, but now it can't return any value from the forEach method. Could my conditions in the if statement be wrong?

Comment: I found a second if with the ; problem I corrected it, but not sure if the result is correct. From what I see thought we fixed the ifs

Answer (score 0):

I've optimized it a bit - it was the `;` in the ifs:

```
holiday.forEach(element => {
    if (new Date(element) >= startDate && new Date(element) <= endDate) {
        if ((new Date(element).getDay() % 6) !=0) {
            days--;
        }
    }
});

document.first.days.value = days;
```